# Convert image to vectors in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to convert the following result image (red regions) to vectors
[image]

I use the following code to attach this target

```js
//translate image to shp
var vectors = openedImage.reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
  // geometryType:'centroid',
  geometry: nx, 
  scale: 2000,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
print(vectors);
Map.addLayer(vectors,{},'Vectors');
```

but nothing happened,
`Vectors` layer display nothing:
[image]

In console,print fllowing results:

[image]

The detail code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/66562bcdc8b548484d381b8716231179)
What happended? Why do the vectors not display?

Comment: We cannot help you because we cannot Access your assets 'county' and 'farmArea'. Could you please share them?

Comment: thanks for the reminder,sir.I have shared asset

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, but your scale seems too big. You have to try with lower scales (50, 100, 200…) and find the one that fits you the best.

Comment: Thank you sir!It's amazing

Comment: If my answer was useful, please accept it.To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.